# When did the Arabic numerals appear on clock faces?

Tags: time-keeping

Were the Arabic numerals used in pre-modern times on mechanical clock faces?

Is there a specific point in time when they started to replace Roman numerals?

**Edit:**

Wikipedia article for [Clock face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_face) claims "Clocks using only Arabic numerals first began to appear in the mid-18th century" with remark: *citation needed*.

Wikipedia article for [Arabic numerals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) contains an image of a *Woodcut showing the 16th century astronomical clock of Uppsala Cathedral, with two clockfaces, one with Arabic and one with Roman numerals.* Not disproving the statement above as it contained "only"-clause. The clock in Uppsala also was not a time clock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leonardo Fibonacci is credited with introducing the Arabic numbers (0123456789) into European use with his book, "Liber Abaci," in 1202.  However, clock-face numbers remained Roman Numerals well into the 15th Century, when Arabic numbers began to appear on clocks in Britain.

As to the *first* use of Western Arabic numbers on a clock face. I have found no exact reference. However, I did come across another referencing the Lund Astronomical Clock, built in 1422, in Sweden (http://www.academia.edu/12745170/The_Evidence_for_Islamic_Scientific_Works_in_Medieval_Iceland).

Comment: To be honest, it wasn't uncommon to see Roman Numeral on clock faces in the 1970's (prior to digital watches), IIRC. I think most schools had them just on the principle that it helped teach the numeral system.

Comment: @T.E.D. I still have a Roman Numeral clock for my primary clock at home.

Comment: @macraf  I'm having trouble relocating my reference.  However, I did come across another referencing the Lund Astronomical Clock, built in 1422, in Sweden (http://www.academia.edu/12745170/The_Evidence_for_Islamic_Scientific_Works_in_Medieval_Iceland).  I hope this will help.

Comment: In the early 1990s I bought a **new** wrist watch with Roman numerals on it & only stopped using it recently when the self charging mechanism stopped working.